# Regular expressions - can't match Cyrillic characters with \w

Tags: java, regex

Task:

> The task must be solved using regular expressions without using container classes.
>
> Input: text (may consist of Latin and Cyrillic). Output: source text, but the case of the first character of each word, which consists of three or more characters, must be inverted.
>
> To consider a word as a sequence containing only letters (all other characters are not included in the word). Create a static convert method that converts input to output.
>
> Example Input data
>
> ```
> When I was younger
> I never needed
> Прощай, со всех вокзалов поезда
> уходят в Дальние Края
> ```
>
> Example Output
>
> ```
> when I Was Younger
> I Never Needed
> прощай, со Всех Вокзалов Поезда
> Уходят в дальние края
> ```

My attempt:

```
public static String convert(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\W&&[\\d]]?[\\w&&[\\D]]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        if (m.group().length() >= 3) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(sb.charAt(m.start()))) {
                sb.setCharAt(m.start(), Character.toLowerCase(sb.charAt(m.start())));
            } else {
                sb.setCharAt(m.start(), Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(m.start())));
            }

        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I need output :

```
when I Was Younger
I Never Needed
прощай, со Всех Вокзалов Поезда
Уходят в дальние края
```

but I have:

```
when I Was Younger
I Never Needed
Прощай, со всех вокзалов поезда
уходят в Дальние Края
```

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code. In particular, pay close attention to where you call `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()`. You should also pull out intermediate results and assign them to variables. You are trying to do too much all in a single line of code.

Comment: Seems like either `Character.isUpperCase` or `toUpperCase`/`toLowerCase` may not work for Cyrillic characters.  Add in some print statements or use your debugger to see if I'm right.

Comment: Could be useful: [Using Locales with Java's toLowerCase() and toUpperCase()](//stackoverflow.com/q/11063102)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Debugging the problem

`\w` doesn't match Cyrillic characters. I worked this out by printing the matched groups within your while loop:

```
System.out.println(m.group());
```

Printed:

> When
>   
> I
>   
> was
>   
> younger
>   
> I
>   
> never
>   
> needed

None of the other words matched.

#### Solution 1

To match Cyrillic characters too, you can use `\p{L}`. If you use `{3}` to match three characters you can avoid having to do the length check in the loop. `\b` matches a boundary character. Putting it all together:

```
public static String convert(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\p{L}{3}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        char firstChar = sb.charAt(m.start());
        if (Character.isUpperCase(firstChar)) {
            sb.setCharAt(m.start(), Character.toLowerCase(firstChar));
        } else {
            sb.setCharAt(m.start(), Character.toUpperCase(firstChar));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Produces:

> when I Was Younger
>   
> I Never Needed
>   
> прощай, со Всех Вокзалов Поезда
>   
> Уходят в дальние края

#### Solution 2

Or, if you want to be *really* swish, use a positive lookahead (non-capturing group) and the matcher `replaceAll` method which takes a lambda:

```
public static String convert(String input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\p{L})(?=\\p{L}{2})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    return m.replaceAll(match -> {
        char ch = match.group().charAt(0);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
            return "" + Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        }
        return "" + Character.toUpperCase(ch);
    });
}
```

Also produces:

> when I Was Younger
>   
> I Never Needed
>   
> прощай, со Всех Вокзалов Поезда
>   
> Уходят в дальние края

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Character.isUpperCase(sb.charAt(m.start()))) {
    sb.setCharAt(m.start(), Character.toLowerCase(sb.charAt(m.start())));
} else {
    sb.setCharAt(m.start(), Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(m.start())));
}
```

You need to debug this piece of code. One way to do that is to break up the complexity and reduce the repetition by assigning intermediate results to their own variables:

```
char firstChar = sb.charAt(m.start());
if (Character.isUpperCase(firstChar)) {
    char lowerChar = Character.toLowerCase(firstChar);
    sb.setCharAt(m.start(), lowerChar);
} else {
    char upperChar = Character.toUpperCase(firstChar);
    sb.setCharAt(m.start(), upperChar);
}
```

Now you can print out the values of these variables to inspect them.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is that by default `\w` accepts only English alphabet. To let it match alphabetical characters from other languages you need to add [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) flag:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\W&&[\\d]]?[\\w&&[\\D]]+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
//                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also your pattern doesn't look right (or it is simply unreadable since it is not clear what main idea behind it is). Since in this example you want to modify only words which have at least 3 characters you could describe them as

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\p{Alpha})(\\p{Alpha}{2,})", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

where

- in group 1 we would store first character
- in group 2 we would store rest of characters.

This way your code could look like:

```
public static String convert(String input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\p{Alpha})(\\p{Alpha}{2,})", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    return m.replaceAll(match -> {
        char firstChar = match.group(1).charAt(0);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(firstChar)) {
            return Character.toLowerCase(firstChar) + match.group(2);
        } else {
            return Character.toUpperCase(firstChar) + match.group(2);
        }
    });
}
```